# How to remove first word from a sentence in swift

Tags: ios, swift, string, xcode

I know how to remove first character from a word in swift like this:

```
var data = "CITY Singapore"
data.removeFirst()
print(data)//ITY Singapore
```

what i want is to remove the first word and space so the result is "Singapore".
How can i remove the first word and leading space in swift?

Comment: Can the string begin with a space? Are strings with more than one space between words valid strings? If yes should they be normalized? Can it be that the words are separated by other characters that spaces?

Answer (score 3):

You can try

```
let data = "CITY Singapore"
let res = data.components(separatedBy: " ").dropFirst().joined(separator: " ") 
print(res)
```

Or

```
let res = data[data.range(of: " ")!.upperBound...] // may crash for no " " inside the string
```

Comment: If the string includes a space at the beginning this would result in "CITY Singapore"

Comment: @LeoDabus the op said words of a sentence i think no sentence should start with a space ?

Comment: It all depends where the string is coming from. Anyway it is just a comment about the behaviour when using this method.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can go with this too

```
let strData = "CITY Singapore"

if let data = strData.components(separatedBy: " ").dropFirst().first {
    // do with data
}
else {
    // fallback
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a Regular Expression solution, the benefit is to modify the string in place.

The pattern searches from the beginning of the string to the first space character

```
var data = "CITY Singapore"
if let range = data.range(of: "^\\S+\\s", options: .regularExpression) {
    data.removeSubrange(range)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use String's `enumerateSubstrings` in range method (Foundation) using `byWords` option and remove the first enclosing range. You need also to stop enumeration after removing the range at the first occurrence:

```
var string = "CITY Singapore"
string.enumerateSubstrings(in: string.startIndex..., options: .byWords) { (_, _, enclosingRange, stop) in
    string.removeSubrange(enclosingRange)
    stop = true
}
string  // "Singapore"
```