# How to remove first word from a sentence in flutter - dart

Tags: flutter, dart

Looking for the same solution that was given in swift here - [How to remove first word from a sentence in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65930577/how-to-remove-first-word-from-a-sentence-in-swift).

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void main() {
String words = "hello world everyone";
List<String> word_l = words.split(" ");
String word = word_l.sublist(1,word_l.length).join(" ");
print(word);
}
```

Use as above code to remove first word from words. This work for multiple words more than 2.

Comment: thanks but I'd like to remove the first word like String hello world = "hello world";
print (world). Your example is helpful to remove the character, not the word.

Comment: I changed it now check again

Answer (score 0):

You could just do this:

```
void main() {
  var data = 'CITY Singapore';
  data = data[0];
  print(data);
}
```

Comment: thank you! In my case ,there could be multiple words and I would like to remove the first word. In your example, I could remove 'CITY' so I have only 'Singapore' in my results.